# How to draw a grid on a PictureBox preserving the image it contains?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to draw a grid on the image in a PictureBox.
But, when the grid is drawn, the image disappears.
How can I fix this code? It draws the grid when a CheckBox is checked or I change the grid size using a TrackBar.

```
private void grid()
{
    int x, y;
    int w = pictureBox1.Size.Width;
    int h = pictureBox1.Size.Height;
    int inc = trackBar1.Value;

    BackImage = new Bitmap(w, h);
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Green);

    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(BackImage);
    gr.Clear(SystemColors.Control);

    if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
    {
        myPen.Color = Color.Green;

        for (x = 0; x < w; x += inc)
            gr.DrawLine(myPen, x, pictureBox1.Location.Y, x, h);

        for (y = 0; y < h; y += inc)
            gr.DrawLine(myPen, pictureBox1.Location.X, y, w, y);
    }
    Invalidate();
    myPen.Dispose();
}

private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   grid();
    Refresh();
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   grid();
   Refresh();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (BackImage != null)
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(BackImage, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: `BackImage = new Bitmap(w, h);` this creates a blank image.  You need two image variables.  One for your background, the other for your drawing.  The one for your drawing would just draw the image of the background, and *then* you draw your grid on that.  Or just draw on the PictureBox paint event.

Comment: Set the Bitmap as the `Image` or `BackgroundImage` of the PictureBox and paint the grid on the surface of the control in its Paint event. Use the `BackgroundImage` property if you want to paint other Bitmaps on top of it. The `Image` property if you just need to paint the grid. You didn't say whether, at some point, you want to save the Bitmap along with the grid.

Comment: Thank you!! I put my code on the paint event and it works fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the **Image** property of your PictureBox to your desired image, then use the supplied `e.Graphics` in the **Paint()** event of the PictureBox:

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
        int x, y;
        int w = pictureBox1.Size.Width;
        int h = pictureBox1.Size.Height;
        int inc = trackBar1.Value;

        Graphics gr = e.Graphics;
        if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            for (x = 0; x < w; x += inc)
                gr.DrawLine(Pens.Green, x, 0, x, h);

            for (y = 0; y < h; y += inc)
                gr.DrawLine(Pens.Green, 0, y, w, y);
        }
    }
}
```